# Why does curl give a different response for $_SERVER['REQUESTI_URI'] than browsers?

Tags: php, web, curl

I have a simple test PHP page:

```
<?php
  echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '<br/>';
  echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
```

When I access this page with a browser (I've tested chrome, and links) it gives me the output I'm expecting:

```
10.1.25.222
/test.php
```

But when I access this with `curl 10.1.25.222/test.php`:

```
10.1.25.222<br/>HTTP://10.1.25.222/test.php
```

Giving me the `HTTP_HOST` I'm expecting, but not the `REQUEST_URI` I'm expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only assume that `curl` must be sending the entire URL in its `GET` request. I've tested both methods below against Apache and they both appear to work and give similar results to what you are experiencing:

What most browsers seem to do in their HTTP request:

```
GET /some/path HTTP/1.1
Host: www.domain.com
```

What curl appears to be doing:

```
GET HTTP://www.domain.com/some/path HTTP/1.1
Host: www.domain.com
```

Comment: Okay, do you have any idea why curl does that differently?

Comment: Not really, I was surprised it worked - I though the `GET` line was supposed to only contain the 'file path' part of the URL. It's just the only way I can see for the entire URL to appear in `REQUEST_URI`. A wild guess would be some historic thing, possibly relating to attempts to support virtual hosting (allowing multiple domains on one server) before the HTTP 1.1 spec finalised the `Host` header. If you run `curl` with the `--verbose` or `--trace-ascii` options it should show exactly what it's sending.